# Python trading script - creating global variables using string data from another variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, global-variables

I wrote a basic script that ingests webhook triggers in the form of JSON data and sends buy or sell orders to a separate API.

Each time the script places a buy order, I want to create a global variable that remembers how many shares were purchased so that I can use that variable as a quantity when I exit the position and sell the same number of shares that were purchased each time.

For a single symbol this was fairly simple, but the script will be accepting triggers for multiple symbols, with the webhook message providing a symbol each time it is triggered.

In my head the easiest way to do this to have a global variable called 'quantity' and prepend the name of the variable with the 'symbol' value prepended each time a buy is placed.

```
Example: MSFT_qty = 30
         AAPL_qty = 23
         RAX_qty = 46
```

I don't know how to name a variable using the string contained inside of another variable (or if that is even possible).  When I place a trade on Microsoft stock I would like to create or update a variable called MSFT_qty "webhook.string["symbol"]qty with the number of shares purchased.

I understand that after I close out of a position, I will have an 'orphaned' variable that is doing nothing until the next time I place a trade for that same symbol, and am I ok with that.  I guess I could also delete the variable when I close a position which I assume would not be too difficult?

I don't care if the variables get overwritten with a new quantity, as I don't expect that I will be trading more than one scenario on any single symbol.  If the situation ever arises where I am, I will deal with it (although deleting the variable after selling out of the position also eliminates this risk).

I'm not a developer and am trying to write things as simply as possible for now to eliminate the need to do any deep debugging when problems arise, but am obviously looking to learn and am open to any and all suggestions.

Example of what I am doing for a single position.  (ingesting a webhook which passes a symbol name, calculating how many shares to purchase with $1000 based on realtime quote data, writing the number of shares to a variable and executing the buy order)

```
#Define Market Buy
@app.route ('/equity/buy', methods=['POST'])
def equity_order():
    webhook_message = app.current_request.json_body

#Get realtime price data
    symbol = webhook_message["symbol"]
    response = c.get_quote(symbol)
    x = (response.json()[symbol])
    Price=(x["lastPrice"])

#Write the number of shares purchased to a global variable
    global Coin_Trade_Qty
    Coin_Trade_Qty = round(1000/Price)

    
#Place a market buy order
    response = c.place_order(config.account_id,
    equity_buy_market(symbol,Coin_Trade_Qty))
    print(response)
    return {
        "code": Coin_Trade_Qty
    }
```

Comment: You need to show some code if you want an answer. Also, if you want things to be "simple" and avoid too much debugging then you shouldn't use globals. This is normally a bad practice and will cause more headaches.

Comment: Any time someone wants to use runtime values to "create variables" the right answer is almost always a dictionary or dictionary-like data structure.

Comment: this problem was many times on Stackoverflow. Don't use separated variables but dictoonary `qty = dict()` and later `qty["MSFT"] = 30` `qty["AAPL"] = 23`

Comment: Thanks @pavel I was having some issues with formatting the post so I posted the question first and then added the code I am running for a single symbol/position in an edit.

Comment: @Chris the dictionary is already global and lives outside of a method, and can be written to from any method?

I assume I include the qty = dict() before I start defining any methods and then just add to it each time I place a buy order with  

qty[webhook_message["symbol"]] = 30?

Comment: OK so a dictionary seems to be the obvious answer now that I am reading through it and understanding how it works....  but how do I write date from a variable to the dictionary (what is the proper syntax)?

If I have data coming in from webhook_message["symbol"]  how do I write that to the dictionary with the calculated value?

I'm sure I can google this pretty easily but since we are here... how do I delete entries from the dictionary once I sell the stock and close a position?